# EditText != vacío dentro de un RadioGroup no trabaja

Tags: java, android

Trato de validar el contenido del EditText pero no funciona, este es mi código:

```
public class Cadenas6 extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText valor;
    RadioGroup group;
    TextView resultado;
    int x;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        valor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        group = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        resultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);


            group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                    x = Integer.parseInt(valor.getText().toString());

                    if (valor.getText().toString().isEmpty())// aquí no funciona!
                        valor.setError("ERROR");
                    else{

                            if (checkedId == R.id.Binario) {
                                resultado.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.toBinaryString(x)));
                            } else if (checkedId == R.id.Octal) {
                                resultado.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.toOctalString(x)));
                            } else if (checkedId == R.id.Hexadecimal) {
                                resultado.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.toHexString(x)));
                            }
                            }
                    }
            });
    }
}
```

El problema lo tengo en esta línea:

```
 if (valor.getText().toString().isEmpty())
```

Comment: Braian edite un poco tu pregunta y agrego opciones para validar el contenido dentro de tu EditText, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

En este caso es incorrecto usar unicamente el método `isEmpty()`, puedes usar el método [`trim()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/lang/String.html#trim()) para eliminar los espacios. puedes también validar el contenido de esta forma, usando el método `equals()`:

```
if (valor.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
```

o de esta forma usando `matches()` :

```
String sValor  = valor.getText().toString().trim();
if (sValor.matches("")) {
```

o de esta otra forma:

```
String sValor  = valor.getText().toString().trim();
    if (sValor.length() ==0) {
```

- El método [`trim()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/lang/String.html#trim()) se utiliza para eliminar los espacios en los extremos de la cadena de caracteres.